# Why does xp_msver return unicode on some installations of SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, visual-foxpro

Looking at various installations of SQL Server, sometimes the 4th column returned by [`xp_msver`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187372.aspx) will sometimes be [`nvarchar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186939.aspx) and sometimes it will be [`varchar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176089.aspx).  This appears to have no bearing on the version of SQL Server, since I see some copies of SQL Server 2000 up to 2012 return varchar, while others return nvarchar.  This also does not seem to have a bearing on Windows version or bitness.

Why does this happen?  and is there a way to either configure the output or know what data type will be used beforehand?

***Edit***: I am using Visual FoxPro to query this information, which has a number of issues dealing with unicode. So, I need to know how to handle the data and convert it to ANSI/single byte encoding - if it isn't already. I understand the limitations of ANSI/single byte, but the loss of data is considered acceptable here.

```
sqlexec(connhandle, "exec xp_msver")
```

If ADO were in the picture, I would just use the data type properties inherit in [RecordSets](http://www.w3schools.com/ado/prop_field_type.asp), but i am limited to FoxPro and its own cursor functionality. When pulled into FoxPro, the `Character_Value` column - the 4th column in question here - is considered a [MEMO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa975373%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) data type, which is a fancy way of saying a string (of some kind or even binary data) possibly longer than 255 characters. It is really a catchall for long strings and any data types that FoxPro cannot handle, which is extremely unhelpful in this case.

There is a [Microsoft KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/191867) that explicitly uses `xp_msver` from FoxPro and states that SQL Server 7.0 and greater always returns Unicode for the stored procedure, but this is not always the case.  Also, since `xp_msver` it is a stored procedure `sp_help` and `sp_columns` aren't of any use here.

In all honesty, I would prefer using [`SERVERPROPERTY()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174396.aspx), but it is not supported in SQL Server 7.0, which is a requirement. I would prefer not to overcomplicate the code by having different queries for different versions of SQL Server. Also, using [`@@version`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177512.aspx) is not a good option, since it would require parsing the text, would be prone to bugs, and doesn't provide all the information I need.

Comment: Compare the server collations on the different machines.

Comment: Can you explain what your actual problem is? It isn't obvious from your question why this behaviour is an issue for you. You might also want to clarify how you're executing `xp_msver` (with or without a parameter) and how you're inspecting the result set to identify the data types.